# Soft Question About Turkish Universities

Tags: soft-question

I am a 12th grader from turkey, I recently did well in the centralized exam, now I have to choose between the University of Bilkent Mathematics and METU Mathematics, I plan on doing my PhD abroad so if you have had experience with either of these universities then which one would you prefer, and which one has better international standing? I am mainly interested in partial differential equations and functional analysis so if anyone works in those fields then id like to ask have you ever heard of either of those universities or had a chance to study with someone from those and if you did, then which one would you consider being a better option?
I am terribly sorry if this question violates any site rules, I wanted to have an international perspective during the choosing process.

Comment: Unfortunately opinion-based questions are off-topic here. You can try asking [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) or on Academia SE (after making it less opinion-based).